Unable to set the value of a multimedia link field in a ui extension
I'm trying to write a UI extension for Experience Space, which gets the ID of an image from a third-party service, converts it into an ECL uri and inserts a multimedia link to this (stub) item.
When I call the setValue method with this ECL uri (a string) as a parameter, I'm getting this error when I try to save the component:
Invalid cast from 'System.String' to 'Sdl.Tridion.ContentManager.OpenApi.Dto.Link'
So I guess I need to construct some sort of Link object and pass that as parameter to setValue. But I cannot figure out how to do that.
By the way: I was able to create an extension of the classic UI in the same way. I found out that as long as the UI passes a correct ECL URI as a value, Tridion will create the stub and construct the link. I hope the same is true for Experience Space.

Indeed, Core Service REST is "ECL-aware", meaning you can provide ECL URIs instead of TCM URIs.  If a CM Stub is needed under the hood, it will be created automatically. And, indeed, a link property has to be of type Link. Unfortunately, my knowledge of the XS frontend it too limited to explain how you can do that.

You are correct, you need a Link object instead of just a string (ECL URI) as a value. Link object looks like this:
interface Link {
  $type: 'Link';
  IdRef: string;
  Title?: string;
}

So, most probably you need to call setValue({ $type: 'Link', IdRef: 'ecl:ecl_uri_example' })
Let me know if it works, otherwise I will try to come up with real example.

That was it, thanks!
